# verilog ; can't use "string" type in $display

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, icarus

I'm using a recent master branch build of icarus verilog.

Should I expect the following to run?

```
module string_display ();

//reg [10:0][7:0] x = "initial";
string x = "initial";

always @* begin
  $display ("x = %s",x);
end

initial begin

  // Assign new string 
  x = "aaaaa";
  #1

  // Assign new string     
  x = "bbbb";
  #1

  #1 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

The above gives

```
internal error: 18vvp_fun_anyedge_sa: recv_string(initial) not implemented
vvp: vvp_net.cc:2972: virtual void vvp_net_fun_t::recv_string(vvp_net_ptr_t, const string&, vvp_context_t): Assertion `0' failed.
```

However, if I define 'x' as a reg by uncommenting the line above then it works as expected ...

```
x =       aaaaa
x =        bbbb
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: "***not implemented***". That means it recognizes what you want to do, but it has not been implemented yet.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not expect Icarus Verilog to support the `string` keyword, which was introduced in the IEEE Std 1800 for SystemVerilog.

According to the [Icarus website](http://iverilog.icarus.com/):

> The compiler proper is intended to parse and elaborate design
>   descriptions written to the IEEE standard *IEEE Std 1364-2005*. This is
>   a fairly large and complex standard, so it will take some time to fill
>   all the dark alleys of the standard, but that's the goal.

There is no mention of IEEE Std 1800.

You can look at the `extensions.txt` file from the github site, which states:

> Icarus Verilog supports certain extensions to the baseline IEEE1364
>   standard. Some of these are picked from extended variants of the
>   language, such as SystemVerilog, ...

But, there is no mention of `string` there.

I tried your code with the `-g2012` option on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/), but I get the same error.  You could try it on your version.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something similar, and it worked for me:

```
module testit;

integer  code; 
string str;
string word_0;
string word_1;
string word_2;
string word_3;
string word_4;

integer file;

initial begin
    //file = $fopenr(" ../../testcase/testcase_4x4.txt");
    
    str    = "this is a test... 1, 2, 3";
    
    code = $sscanf(str, "%s %s %s %s %s", 
                    word_0, word_1, word_2, word_3, word_4);
                    
    $display("Number of words: %0d", code);
    
    $display("words[0]:(%-0s)", word_0);
    $display("words[1]:(%-0s)", word_1);
    $display("words[2]:(%-0s)", word_2);
    $display("words[3]:(%-0s)", word_3);
    $display("words[4]:(%-0s)", word_4);    
end

endmodule
```

Icarus Verilog Run Command:

```
    iverilog -g2012 .\testit.sv       
    vvp -i a.out
```

Output:

```
Number of words: 5
words[0]:(this)
words[1]:(is)
words[2]:(a)
words[3]:(test...)
words[4]:(1,)
```

Icarus Verilog Version:

PS> iverilog -v
Icarus Verilog version 11.0 (devel) (s20150603-612-ga9388a89)